# Bootstrap installation verified but still unable to load in Angular 13 component

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, npm-install, angular-ui-bootstrap

Not able to load Bootstrap to one of component in new Angular 13 Project.

1. angular.json file has below lines already added:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              ],
```

2. I verified that I have bootstrap installed at above location.
3. I installed bootstrap using below node command:
   npm install bootstrap@3

Comment: Issue solved now, I did:
ctrl+c : stop terminal.
ng serve --open

It restarted the app and things worked well afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks fine.
I usually also install `@ng-bootstrap/bootstrap`, to use bootstrap modals.

The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) mentions this compatibility table, but these are really just guidelines.

[image: compatibility]

I've been using the following versions with Angular 14.0.6, without any issues at all. So, I'm pretty sure that you could use them with Angular 13 as well.

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
```

And as you mentioned, I have in the angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```